# ANSI C Video Game Item System

Tags: rpg, c

I am looking to program my own little **[Role Playing Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-playing_game#Electronic_media)** using...

- [ANSI C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) or "standard C", (NOT C++) as my programming language
- The [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/) development library

I have got a very basic and simple type of game up and going,
(I am learning ANSI C as I develop this hobby game).

I want to implement an item system to the game, so I have been looking through the internet for advice, but it seems like the closest I can get are solutions to C++, Java and other *object oriented languages*. I can't seem to find a good implementation in C, other than **[THIS](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_C_With_Game_Concepts/Designing_A_Roleplaying_Game#Inventory_System)** guide, so I thought I could post this question specifically for ANSI C both for me and for others that might be looking to achieve the same goal.

My attack plan is to create a [struct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)) to lay out a blue print of what an item is, much like a [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) in an OOP language. Then, perhaps create an array that defines objects of this type and fills in the details for each item.

---

This is what I have so far:

```
#ifndef ITEMS_H_INCLUDED
#define ITEMS_H_INCLUDED

/* Create a structure that represent an item.
   @see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm */
typedef struct Item {
    //Unique ID to be used as a reference to the item.
    unsigned int id;

    //Name of the item.
    char name[20];

    //Brief description about the item.
    char description[50];

    //Defines the category of the item; equipment, consumable, etc...
    unsigned char type;

    //Used for equipment; defines the strength of the weapon/armor.
    unsigned char stats[4];

    //The X and Y coordinates of the starting point of the sprite.
    unsigned int sprite[2];
}item;

#endif // ITEMS_H_INCLUDED
```

The **id-attribute** will be used to spawn the item in different locations, such as...

- In the player's inventory
- In a store
- On the floor to be picked up

I'm looking to [hard code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) the item DATA in the source file, but I'm also open for solutions like reading item information from a file, and such.

Comment: Can you clarify, what is your question? Did you encounter a specific problem in making your system so far that we can help you solve? Is there a specific gap or missing feature in the system as you've written it thus far that you need help implementing?

Comment: I have an issue conceptualizing it and I'm not sure which approach/implementation is the best, most effective way and which is most scalable. Seeing that C is not an OOP language, how would I translate an item system written in OOP languages like C++ or Java, into a language like C?
I hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: What specific benefit do you observe in OOP implementations that you need help adapting to C?

Comment: Defining the different items and creating an instance of the item.

Comment: Cool. Now what distinguishes those item types from one another? We see your `type` field — is that not sufficient for what you need? How have you tried instantiating an item so far? We really need to see what your requirements are and where you've hit a wall chasing them before we can help you find the appropriate door in that wall to get to where you want.

Comment: I have considererd omitting the id-field and creating an array of item-objects, then use the array index as a reference to which item is in a slot. Something like this:

//0th entry is a wooden dagger.
item items[10] = { "Wooden Dagger", "A small knife made from oak", 3, { 6, 4, 12, 4 }, { 32, 128 } etc... };

And then say:

unsigned int inventory[28];
inventory[0] = 0; //Add a wooden dagger to the 0th slot in inventory?

Could this be a way to create the item system, or am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Sounds great. Did you encounter a specific problem with this approach that you need help solving? We're really not a sounding board to get open-ended feedback on an idea. We're problem-solvers. If you have an idea that seems like it could work, you're probably right, so just try it and find out!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but I do encounter a compilation error while trying to compile with GCC. Above my Item-struct I have the following code: "typedef enum item_type { armor, consumable, quest, weapon } type;", and beneath the struct, I have the following code:

"item items[2] = {
    { "Wooden dagger", "A small knife made from oak.", weapon, { 6, 4, 12, 4 }, { 0, 0 } },
    { "Red cape", "A beautiful piece of equipment.", armor, { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 30, 0 } }
};"

The compilation output reads:
"error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: Sounds like a programming problem to ask about on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

As for the way to store informations regarding items and stuff, there is nothing closer from a class in C than a struct. I would recommend using it.

As for retrieving datas from a file, I advise checking the [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) part of Stack Exchange considering it is dedicated to programming techniques and issues. A dozen of topics are about using files in C since its a bit tricky and can easily be done wrong (as everything in C I guess).